# Long delay for iOS consumer

Tags: c#, ios, .net, swift, rabbitmq

I use RabbitMQ and CloudAMQP server to send messages between 2 applications.

It takes **less than a second** to send message between two .Net console applications or from iOS app to .Net console application.

But if I send the message from .Net console application to iOS app, it takes **7-10 seconds**.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.send()
        //self.receive()        
    }
    func send() {        

        let delegate = RMQConnectionDelegateLogger()
        let conn = RMQConnection(uri: "...", delegate: delegate)

        conn.start()
        let ch = conn.createChannel()
        let q = ch.queue("hello")
        ch.defaultExchange().publish("Hello World!".data(using: .utf8), routingKey: q.name)
        self.lblText.text = "Sent 'Hello World!'"
        conn.close()
    }

    func receive() {        
        let delegate = RMQConnectionDelegateLogger()
        let conn = RMQConnection(uri: "...", delegate: delegate)

        conn.start()
        let ch = conn.createChannel()
        let q = ch.queue("hello")
        q.subscribe({(_ message: RMQMessage) -> Void in           
            self.lblText.text = String(data: message.body, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        })
    }
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be improper use of UI calls from a background thread, but it's impossible to tell from the outside.

Your receive function is making a call `subscribe` that takes a completion handler. If that completion handler is run on a background thread then you will need to wrap any UI calls inside the completion handler to a call to the main thread. Try this change:

```
func receive() {        
    let delegate = RMQConnectionDelegateLogger()
    let conn = RMQConnection(uri: "...", delegate: delegate)

    conn.start()
    let ch = conn.createChannel()
    let q = ch.queue("hello")
    q.subscribe({(_ message: RMQMessage) -> Void in
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        //Wrap UIKit code in a call to DispatchQueue.main.async()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {           
          self.lblText.text = String(data: message.body, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------------
    })
}
```

Comment: I just added the code. I use 2 simple methods: send() and receive().
I got this code from tutorial.

Comment: Remember that rule of thumb. When you use an async method that takes a completion handler, find out if the completion handler is run on a background thread. If it is, you need to wrap your UIKit calls in a call to the main thread like my example code above.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that